# Cortar imagem 'a mão livre'

Tags: php, imagem

Olá,
Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de um Closet Virtual, onde o usuário faria o upload de imagem de suas roupas e salvaria no sistema. Mas tenho um problema com o fundo das imagem, queria algo que possibilitasse o usuário recortar a roupa da imagem que ele fez o upload, como se fosse a ferramenta 'caneta' do photoshop. Se poderem ajudar, ficaria grata.

Comment: Em que linguagem de programação você está desenvolvendo ?

Comment: Com PHP. Estava tentando fazer essa parte com o Jcrop, mas ele corta apenas em formato quadrado. @Kevin.F

Comment: Isso é complexo. Pesquise por "javascript polygonal lasso" ou termos similares.

Comment: Exemplo de "polygonal lasso" semelhante a ferramenta do Photoshop: http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/180/

Comment: É isso que eu preciso, vou pesquisar, obrigado. @DanielOmine